# Wordpress Add javascript:void(0); to menu link item?

Tags: menus, themes

I want to add `javascript:void(0);` to menu link item instead of `#` but it is not accepting any JavaScript.
Now i am thing to replace `#` with `javascript:void(0);` using filters, but could not find the appropriate filter for the task.

Can any one tell me  which filter can be used for this task.

Note. I know this could be done with javascript/jQuery but this is for SEO purposes so have to do it with PHP on server side and render the correct html for google Spider, to avoid duplicate URL issue.

Comment: Why do you wanna do that ?

Comment: Please specify do you want to change the particular menu item or all of them?

Comment: any link that have #

Comment: @Sumit The SEO Team Want so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not sure how it does effect the SEO but just to answer this
>   question:-

You can not save menu item with `javascript:void(0);` because WordPress filter the URL using function [`esc_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/esc_url) thus removing bad values. And it all happens in Nav Walker class. So you need to alter the URL when WordPress done with filtering and returning final safe HTML.

You can use filter `walker_nav_menu_start_el` if your theme does not have custom nav menu walker class OR does have this filter in walker class.

Example:-

```
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse_226884_replace_hash', 999);
/**
 * Replace # with js
 * @param string $menu_item item HTML
 * @return string item HTML
 */
function wpse_226884_replace_hash($menu_item) {
    if (strpos($menu_item, 'href="#"') !== false) {
        $menu_item = str_replace('href="#"', 'href="javascript:void(0);"', $menu_item);
    }
    return $menu_item;
}
```

Comment: This is just perfect :)

Comment: Important note for those who are new to Wordpress (just like me): you should make edits in `functions.php` file of your active theme (`/wp-content/themes/yourthemename`).

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Method**

First thing you need to do is add a new menu item in your menu. You can do that by going to Appearance » Menus. You want to add a custom link so give it the label you want. In the URL field, enter the # sign. Once done, click on the Add to Menu button. Save your menu once this custom link is added to the menu.
Adding a custom link to the menu without URL

Now click on the drop down arrow next to this custom link to edit this menu item. Go ahead and remove the pound sign from the URL field and save your menu. If you go to your live website, then you will see a menu item without link. You can add sub menus to this menu item and link them to any page or custom link you want.
Removing # sign and creating a menu without any link.

check this link for more detail.

http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-titles-in-wordpress-menu-without-linking-to-a-page/